# Azure App Service stdout is empty for ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.2

Unable to log error in stdout log from ASP.NET Core 2.2 in Azure App Service. The stdout log files is created but empty.

The web.config configuration in `<system.webServer>`:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\xxx.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can be solved by temporary removing the `hostingModel="InProcess"` then errors are logged in the stdout log files.

`hostingModel="InProcess"` removed:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\xxx.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
```

Comment: Is that a known issue with the inprocess hosting model?

Comment: Thanks.  Had no idea why my logs were zero byte.  This fixed it for me.